# Add alternative text to a phrase in a document file

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice

I use LibreOffice Writer and I want to insert an alternative text to a specific phrase in the document, how can I do it?

Example if we have an image in the document we can make double left click and add the alternative text like this:
[image: example]

Is it possible to make the same if we select a whole phrase of text? If yes how? And if No is there any other proposal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative text in 'word'/odt  documents is actually intended as the 'alt' attribute in HTML (web) pages:

> The alt attribute provides alternative information for an image if a
>   user for some reason cannot view it (because of slow connection, an
>   error in the src attribute, or if the user uses a screen reader).
>   (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp)

It's only purpuse is thus to provide the user with information in case he/she can not view the image. Since having alternative text in case some text cannot be displayed is, well, silly, this 'alt' attribute is not defined for pieces of text. Alternatively, you could have a hyperlink pointing to nothing ("#"), which does provide a tooltip attribute.

What is it that you're intending to achieve anyway? It's not going to show up on any prints, which is the intended purpose of Writer... Footnotes (for prints) or Comments (for communication with co-editors) might suit you better.